# Angular scope accessible from inside foreach function

Tags: angularjs, foreach, scope

Is there way to access the scope from inside a foreach function in angular?

```
 $scope.getPlowHistory = function() {
       $scope.plowId = $stateParams.plowId;
       SnowPlowService.getPlowHistory($scope.plowId).then(function(response) {
            $scope.plow = response; 

            angular.forEach($scope.plow,function(value,index){
                $scope.Lat =  value.Latitude;
                $scope.Lng =  value.Longitude;                      
            });
        });
    };
```

I would need $scope.Lat and $scope.Long to be usable in $scope.getPlowHistory() and not just inside the foreach loop.

Thanks!

Comment: $scope _should be_ accessible, based on javascript closures, unless the scope is getting destroyed before the promise resolves. What error are you getting?

Comment: getting "undefined" when trying $scope.getPlowHistory = function() {... console.log($scope.Lat);}; outside the loop.

Comment: no problem accessing it, but you are overwriting the variables in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: true....how do I not do that?

Comment: you probably want an array

Comment: Wait... are you calling `console.log()` after outside of the loop _only_ or outside of the `SnowPlowService.getPlowHistory` request? Because, if you're doing that, it will print out the value before the promise resolves, and, therefor, before `$scope.Lat` or `$scope.Lng` is defined. But, yes, @charlietfl is correct, if you want to store all the values returned, those variables should be an array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't 100% understand what you are trying to do, but something doesn't look right.

```
angular.forEach($scope.plow,function(value,index){
     $scope.Lat = value.Latitude;
     $scope.Lng = value.Longitude;                      
});
```

> Your code is actually updating $scope.Lat and $scope.Lng with the value of the last element of your response.

What I think you are trying to do is something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.plow,function(value,index){
     $scope.Lat[index] = value.Latitude;
     $scope.Lng[index] = value.Longitude;                      
});
```

> So if your result contains three elements, $scope.Lat and $scope.Lng will each contain three elements.

## So to answer your original question, you are probably getting undefined because the results last element is empty for some reason.

I hope that this is what you are looking for, if not comment, and I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: thanks, it helped me understand variables in a loop.

Comment: @nrunit If my answer helped you, please mark it as an accepted answer to help build my reputation.